# Battery percentage only updates when suspending and waking/restarting the computer

Tags: laptop, battery, 19.04

I "revived" an old laptop that was sitting unused for some months (years maybe) from my girlfriend with Xubuntu and I decided to buy a new battery since the original was completely dead, it has the same specs from the original and it is allegedly compatible with it, it charged to 100% and then I removed the AC adaptor, but the percentage counter never dropped from 100% and after some hours the laptop just died. I plugged the AC adaptor and turned it on again and it said it was charging, but never left the 0%, so I tried resetting and it updated the percentage, later I tried suspending it and it also update the battery percentage. `acpi -v` and `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` both show the same percentage. What's wrong with it?
PS: my girlfriend later told me that the old battery had the same problem and she thinks the problem started when she installed Fedora on it, but may have started in Windows and she just don't remember.
PS2: I have to release the money to the seller I bought the battery online in less than 48h, I at least need to know it isn't a problem with the battery itself.

Comment: If you plug in the AC adapter for 8 hours, unplug it and use the laptop for 5 to 8 hours until the battery dies then it sounds like it is a good battery.

Comment: I didn't left it plugged for 8 hours, is it necessary nowadays? Why the percentage doesn't update?

Comment: I was dealing with the issue of returning battery within 48 hours only. Plug it in before you go to bed and shut off laptop. In morning time how long it lasts on battery power. In Windows 8 to 10 hours is great. In Ubuntu 5 to 8 hours can be great. If it only lasts a couple of hours though you should considering returning in your 48 hour window. I thought this was the question you were most concerned about....

Comment: The problem was solved through a BIOS update, the specifics are in this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/bp4ggs/battery_percentage_only_updates_when_suspending/)!